# Array of deferred objects working on local server but not a real server

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using an array of deferred objects so that I can show and hide a loading icon when a collection of Backbone models are finished saving on the server.

This is my code:

```
            $('div.loading').show();

            self.collection.each(function(item) {
                item.url = "/Foo/FooBar";
                defs.push(item.save());
            });

            // when everything is saved 
            $.when.apply(null, defs).then(function() {
                $('div.loading').text("Save Complete");
                $('div.loading').fadeOut(1500);
                self.render();
                alert("It's finished!");
            });
```

Is there any generic reason why the alert never get's called and the loading gif just stays on the screen.

I checked the calls through the browser and they all return a 200 status so there aren't any server-side errors happening.

Comment: Add a second function to .then and log the arguments, most likely one of the deferred are being rejected.

Comment: `.then(function(){/*theoriginalfunction*/},function(){console.log(arguments)});`

Comment: Like this:    $.when.apply(null, defs).then(function() {
                   
                }, function() { console.log(defs); });

Comment: `arguments` instead of `defs`

Comment: It just says [object Arguments] but I can't click on it.

Comment: install firebug if you're using firefox, if you're using IE, don't use IE for it's console. You can try `console.dir(arguments)` too

Comment: I'm using chrome. I'll try console.dir. Thanks.

Comment: weird. in chrome logging arguments gives me an array-like structure. Sorry for the wrong assumption

Comment: OK, I did get a parser error.  -   SyntaxError
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "Unexpected token <"

Comment: chances are you're either hitting a 404 page, or a server error.

Comment: You should be able to see which by going to your Network tab.